# Excel: How to change multiple data from one row to multiple

Tags: excel

I am new here so I will try to explain best I can and include a picture.

Basically I need to organize data within excel where I have multiple "returns" within one cell and need to convert this from A1 to A1 - A5 for example, refer to pictures for a better example of what is needed.

Please view picture below for how I currently have it and how I want to have it.  Please help with this as this will save a lot of time!

[This is how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pO00.png)

[This is how I need the information to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s20i.png)

This is needed for several hundred rows of information with the same format, please help me find a quick solution on how to turn this data from picture 1 to look like picture 2 in a fast manner, I am not sure the fastest way to go about this.

Please note that in picture one the information is all in row 1 and picture 2 the information is all row 1 - 5.

I should also note that the cells in picture 1 are not merged but rather input through "alt enter" and I have tried to find a few methods online but do not know how to go about this

Comment: You have to unmerge the cells and the values will be there in the first cell of the unmerged range and then copy it till the next value appears. You can loop through the B column to check if merge=true then make it false , then you can copy the values of the range to the rest of the cell

Comment: Can you provide more specific information about the step you have tried to do this?

Comment: I have tried to split cells, paste special (transpose), and manually changing this set up but I am not as tech savvy and all the options I listed take too long, as there are about 600 rows I need to complete this action with.  Should also note that the cells are not merged but rather I were input with alt - enter

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
lr = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
For i = 2 To lr
If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).MergeCells = True Then
Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 2).MergeArea.Address).UnMerge
Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 3).MergeArea.Address).UnMerge
nr = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2)).End(xlDown).Row
If nr < lr Then
nr1 = nr
Else
nr1 = lr + 1
End If
For j = i To nr1 - 1
Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
Next j
End If
i = nr - 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Try the above code. This might help you.

```
Sub test()
Dim arr() As String
dim arr2() as string

For i = 2 To Rows.Count
If Not Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
val2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
val3 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
arr = Split(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, Chr(10))
arr2 = Split(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value, Chr(10))
cnt = UBound(arr)
Sheets(1).Rows(i & ":" & i + cnt - 1).EntireRow.Insert
For j = i To i + cnt
Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value = arr(j - i)
Sheets(1).Cells(j, 4).Value = arr2(j - i)
Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value = val2
Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value = val3
Next j

i = i + cnt
Else: Exit For
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Make sure you dont have any blanks between rows in A column. this code will work for value seperated by alt+ enter.

Comment: this is if the cells are merged. If you did it by alt enter then you have to split the values across cells.

Comment: i edited and added a new block of code for dealing with Alt+enter cases